# Validar campos no react native

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-hooks

Tenho uns campos de input, ambos estão setados os estados. Gostaria de fazer com que só permita o clique no botão se esses campos estiverem preenchidos. obs:.Estou Usando Hooks

```
const [ name, setName ] = useState('');
const [ user, setUser ] = useState('');
const [ datanascimento, setDataNascimento ] = useState('');
const [ tel, setTel ] = useState('');
const [ email, setEmail] = useState('');



 <TouchableOpacity
      onPress={() => navigation.navigate('DeliverymanPhotos')}
      style={styles.btnPrimary}>
      <Text style={styles.btnPrimaryText}>
        Confirmar
      </Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
```

Comment: Não é só você criar uma função que verifique isso e colocar ela no `onClick` do `TouchableOpacity`?

Answer (score 0):

A forma mais simples de fazer isso é verificando se os campos estão preenchidos, ex:
Se o campo nome e email for igual a "" altera o valor do parâmetro disabled para **true** caso contrario para **false**

Comment: Seria legal ter um código de exemplo

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer uma verificação antes de navegar, se todos os estados forem diferentes de uma string vazia, dai poderá navegar.

```
const [ name, setName ] = useState('');
const [ user, setUser ] = useState('');
const [ datanascimento, setDataNascimento ] = useState('');
const [ tel, setTel ] = useState('');
const [ email, setEmail] = useState('');

  function checkToNavigate() {
    if((name, user, dataNascimento, tel, email) !== '')
      return navigation.navigate('DeliverymanPhotos');
  }


  <TouchableOpacity
    onPress={() => checkToNavigate()}
    style={styles.btnPrimary}>

    <Text style={styles.btnPrimaryText}>
      Confirmar
    </Text>
  </TouchableOpacity>
```